# What's the difference between getLastOrderId() and getLastRealOrderId()?

Tags: checkout, sales-order, session, singleton

Does anyone have a quick and dirty explanation of the differences?

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()
```

I generally would use `getLastOrderId()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: `getLastRealOrderId` => the increment ID (the order # shown to a customer after checkout. `getLastOrderId` => the entity ID of the order in the database.

---

### Background

The method `getLastRealOrderId` are magic methods, meaning they're getters for the properties `last_real_order_id` and `last_order_id`. They are set on the checkout session during a successful order placement by `Mage_Checkout_Model_Onepage::saveOrder`.

The two data properties are set in tandem once the order is successful. - `getLastRealOrderId` was introduced in Magento 1.8 CE on the checkout session along with the previously available `getLastOrderId` because it would require another model load (e.g. another database query) get get the increment id, which is *usually* what you want, if you wanted access to that information to display on the site or use in code.

By setting it on the checkout session directly, **when it's available**, after a successful order they prevent a developer from writing code which **may adversely affect performance.**

Comment: I'm sending order id's/entity id's using curl/json for an approve conversion API. So it looks like i should be using getLastOrderId() rather than getLastRealOrderId()

Comment: Can you confirm?

Comment: Confirmed. <!-- more content -->

Comment: Thank you, the reason why i ask is because I'm nearly done but i'm still having an issue. This is for extole. Not sure if you're familiar with them.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117406/curl-and-json-approve-conversion-api

Answer (score -1):

You can get Order entity id from following line:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()
```

You can get Order Increment Id from following line:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()
```

For more clarification go to **app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php**

**saveOrder** method.

```
// add order information to the session
$this->_checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
    ->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl)
    ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
```