# curl and json approve conversion Rest API

Tags: magento-enterprise, rest-api, magento-1.14, json, curl

i'm currently coding a little api for extole approve conversion api. It's only suppose to send data on declined orders which is equal to cancelled in the magento admin.

Here is what i have written so far:

```
$data = array(
   'partner_conversion_id' => Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(),
   'event_status' => 'approve',
   );

$data = '{"partner_conversion_id":"'.Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId().'", "event_status":"approve"}';
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.website.com/v3/events/approve?event_id='.Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "11111-1:111111111111111111111");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = ($result);
```

When i `var_dump($result)` on my success.phtml page i get most of what i'm looking for..

```
string(115) "{"code":"BAD REQUEST","message":"Missing mandatary field value for approval_status","uniqueId":6289418511505278727}"
```

The uniqueId is the partner_conversion_id which seems to be firing correctly.

So the approval status and the message field which is optional i'm not currently able to get.

Why am i getting BAD REQUEST and how do I get my approval_status to fire?